# loadChildren can't find module (lazy loading modules)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-modules

I'm trying to implement lazy loading modules, but the error appears.
My proest uses System.js, maybe I'm wrong to point out the way, how is it calculated?

My app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
imports ...

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'user', loadChildren: 'build/app/profile/user/user.module#UserModule' },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

My user.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
imports...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     CommonModule,
     FormsModule,
     UserRouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [
      UserComponent,
      UserInfoComponent,
      UserEditPasswordComponent
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
      AuthService,
      UserGuard,
      UserService
  ]
  })

  export class UserModule { }
```

My user-router.module.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
imports ...

export const USER_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: UserInfoComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'edit', component: UserEditPasswordComponent },
    { path: 'candidates', component: CandidateListComponent },
    { path: 'add-candidate', component: CandidateAddComponent },
    { path: 'candidates/:id/edit', component: CandidateEditComponent }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(USER_ROUTES)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRouterModule {}
```

Structure and error here:

[Structure of my project:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8plIo.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra9ye.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `app/profile/user/user.module#UserModule` path?